# (AS3) OOP Stage seems offset?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, position, stage

When checking if a movieclip's position is greater than the stage's lenght, why does the Stage seem offset?

For exemple, to hit the right boundaries of the stage I have to write :

```
if(mc.x >= stage.stageWidth/2||mc.x <= -stage.stageWidth/2){
    trace("Boundary hit!");
}
```

while it should be

```
if(mc.x >= stage.stageWidth||mc.x <= 0){
    trace("Boundary Hit!");
}
```

Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the registration point of your MovieClip is where you think it is?

Comment: Yes I have tested with Movieclips 5px wide and have gotten the same results.

Comment: @Jeremie It's not the width I'm referring to - there's a specific point that represents the x and y of an object and your graphics may not be aligned to that point.